# scala get vs match which one to use, given that restult will always be same type?

Tags: scala

Given that match will never be None,
Which style is better or can I improve the first?

```
val tmp = (cols.find(_(0) == id).get)
SomeClass(tmp(0), tmp(1))



cols.find(_(0) == id) match {
          case Some(value)=> SomeClass(value(0), value(1))
          case None=> NotFound("Given id not found")
        }
```

Comment: Using `.get` is highly discouraged, as code based on that doesn't benefit from type safety to make sure all cases are handled.

Comment: there's only one case in this scenario.

Comment: @Sam *there's only one case in this scenario* This can change after code refactorings, new feature implementations etc. Compiler can check pattern matching for exhaustivity. Also you can use `getOrElse`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this a question about style, my answer is that neither of these is the best style. Instead, just keep the value in the `Option`

```
val opt: Option[SomeClass] = cols.find(_(0) == id).map(v => SomeClass(v(0), v(1)))
```

Keep processing/testing inside the `Option` using `foreach`/`exists` etc. until you really need the bare value. There is a very rich set of methods on `Option` that covers most of the things that are needed.

If the rest of the code is structured well, you will likely find that the value never needs to be extracted in a separate operation.